# select rvm gemset in script header

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, rvm

I would like to specify which ruby interpreter and which gemset to use inside the header of my ruby script. Something along the lines of

```
#!/usr/bin/env source /usr/local/lib/rvm && rvm ruby-1.9.2@system
```

would be great.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way to do it...

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p180@system
```

Comment: hmm, none of my systems have any symlinked rubies in /usr/local/bin

Comment: maybe they are just somewhere else on your system?

Answer (score 5):

tcurdt's post is a little misleading. On my system I just set up rvm (ree, 1.8.7, & 1.9.2 rubies) on the system as root. My /usr/local/bin looked like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root rvm   46 Mar 13 06:50 ree-1.8.7-2011.03 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/ruby
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root rvm   44 Mar 13 06:42 ruby-1.8.7-p334 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p334/ruby
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root rvm   44 Mar 11 22:42 ruby-1.9.2-p180 -> /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180/ruby
```

I didn't have a gemset called system as in tcurdt's example. So I believe the appropriate way to achieve what you're after would be like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p180
```

Some explanation of what rvm is doing here: rvm creates wrappers scripts (/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/*) which set things like `GEM_PATH` & `GEM_HOME`. These are needed so that gems can get loaded correctly as part of a specific version of ruby. Links to these wrapper scripts are created under `/usr/local/bin`, when you do a system installation of rvm. If you've installed rvm as yourself they're located here: `$HOME/.rvm/bin`.

It's critical to prefix the shebang line (#!/....) with the `/usr/bin/env`. If you just try and point it directly to a ruby (for e.g. #!/usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p180) will not suffice. This is because these wrappers are not actually the ruby interpreter, they are shell scripts that are sourcing an environment setup prior to calling your script as an argument to the ruby interpreter, like so:

```
source "/usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180" 
exec ruby "$@"
```

the `$@` is your shell script name being passed to ruby.

Finally here's an example script that I put together which I run in a cgi-bin directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p180

puts "Content-Type: text/html"
puts
puts "<html>"
puts "<body>"
puts "<h1>Hello Ruby!</h1>"
puts "<p>shebang: #!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/ruby-1.9.2-p180</p>"
puts "<p>RUBY_VERSION: " + RUBY_VERSION + "</p>"
puts "<p>RUBY_PLATFORM: " + RUBY_PLATFORM + "</p>"
puts "<p>RUBY_RELEASE_DATE: " + RUBY_RELEASE_DATE + "</p>"
puts "</body>"
puts "</html>"
```

Comment: While you are very elaborate that is not the correct answer to the question.

I don't want to just select a certain ruby version but also the gemset! Fortunately rvm creates wrapper scripts not just for the ruby version but also the gemsets. Of course if you don't have a "system" gemset there is no point trying to select it ;)

BTW: Just selecting the ruby version you could also use rvm-shell

Comment: Hadn't noticed rvm-shell. So one could use: 
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/rvm-shell? 

Which ruby & gemset would you end up with?

Answer (score 5):

`#!/usr/bin/env rvm 1.9.3@mygemset do ruby`

Comment: This seems like the cleanest way to accomplish this.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  RVM 1.26.11, Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

Check out this gist :

https://gist.github.com/343545

HTH

Comment: thanks for the link ...unfortunately it does not really provide further insights